# Что означает (visited.add(x) or False)?

Tags: python, алгоритм

```
nums = [1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1]

visited = set()
dup = [x for x in nums if x in visited or (visited.add(x) or False)]

print(dup)  # [1, 5, 1]
```

Здравствуйте,
меня интересует принцип работы алгоритма для нахождения повторяющихся значений списка.

Проблема заключается в 4 строке.
Не понимаю, зачем здесь `(visited.add(x) or False)`?
Что означает этот код?

Comment: Код в текст поместите, пожалуйста (это комментарий в рамках стандартной проверки "первых сообщений").

Comment: Paul, любопытно, а что всё же за источник этого алгоритма? Если там такого много, то вы просто будете терять время и учится странному.

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/find-duplicate-items-python-list/ Я просто искал алгоритм, тот сайт увидел впервые.

Comment: Paul, ясно, тогда лучше его забанить:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше было, конечно, указать источник происхождения данного алгоритма.
Но на мой взгляд, это просто пример нарушения рекомендации языка "ясность важнее лаконичности".

`visited.add(x)` помещает в множество "посещённых" символов новый элемент списка каждый раз, когда идет переход к следующему элементу (но два одинаковых элемента там все равно не может быть согласно природе множества). Так как возвращаемого значения у него нет, то на работу `if` ему не  повлиять. Поместили его туда, вероятно, стремясь написать однострочник, раз синтаксис позволяет. Если так, то это ненужное трюкачество.

Смысла в `False` в скобке рядом с ним я не вижу. Возможно, его туда поместил автор, имея в голове идею, что без него сочетание `x in visited` c `visited.add(x)` даст что-то неверное. Но я не вижу ситуаций, когда этот `False` что-то даёт в выражении с `or`. Можете потестировать сами, если хотите, просто оставив `if x in visited or visited.add(x)`.

Comment: Скорее всего тот, кто писал код, почему-то думал, что `if` должен быть обязательно от `bool`. Но при этом знал, как работает `None or bool` и не смог додумать, что `None` как `bool` воспринимается всегда одинаково как `False`, что в `or`, что в `if` без разницы. )

Comment: @CrazyElf, самое неправильное, что этот кто-то, стремясь написать (вроде как) короче, сделал длиннее, даже не проверив свою идею. Похоже на копирование чьего-то схожего кода без особого анализа, зато с выкладыванием потом, как образца.

Answer (score 5):

Тут используется особенность работы `or` в питоне. Вопреки распостраненному мнению результатом работы `or` является не значение типа `bool`, а значение либо первого либо второго аргументов, а они могут быть и не `bool`.

`A or B`, где `A` и `B` некие выражения работает таким образом:

1. вычисляется выражение `A`. Результат обозначим `a`. Если `a` при приведении к типу `bool` равно `True` (еще по другому говорят значение является правдивым, англ. truthy), результатом `A or B` будет `a`. При этом, что важно отметить, значение выражения `B` вообще не вычисляется.
2. Иначе (т.е. если `bool(a) == False`, значение ложное или falsy) результатом `A or B` будет значение выражения `B`.

Примеры:

| A or B | A | bool(A) | Результат `A or B` | Пояснение |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| False or 1 | False | False | 1 |  |
| [1] or False | [1] | True | [1] | непустой список - truthy |
| [] or 'abc' | [] | False | 'abc' | пустой спискок - falsy |
| None or 12 | None | False | 12 | bool(None) == False |
| 'abc' or 12 | 'abc' | True | 'abc' | непустая строка - truthy |
| '' or 55 | '' | False | 55 | непустая строка - falsy |

Как же `or` работает в `if` если результатом является не `bool`? Просто - значение всего вычисленного выражения приводится к `bool`, т.е. скажем `if [] or 'abc'` будет  истинно т.к. `bool('abc') == True`.

Может возникнуть вопрос: зачем эти сложности?

Такая особенность работы `or` используется для компактной записи условий. Вместо:

```
if x:
   y = x
else:
   y = z
```

Можно написать `y = x or z`.

В примере из вопроса смысла в `or False` в `visited.add(x) or False` нет, так как выражение используется в `if` и значит будет сделано неявное приведение к bool. Значением выражения `visited.add(x)` является `None` и при приведении к `bool` все равно получится `False`.

Вне булевого контекста (т.е. не в if) это имеет значение и следующие две строки работают по разному:

```
y = visited.add(x)            # y будет равно None
y = visited.add(x) or False   # y будет равно False
```